# How can file chunk downloading and merging be implemented in the front-end without encountering memory overflow problems?

Tags: download, frontend

I am currently working on a front-end application and need to implement a feature for downloading large files in chunks. It seems that most existing solutions require concatenating these chunks in memory, which can lead to memory overflow issues when dealing with extremely large files.

I would appreciate guidance or best practices on efficiently handling file chunk downloading in a front-end context without causing memory overflow. Are there any specific techniques, libraries, or design patterns that can help manage the chunks efficiently without overwhelming the browser's memory?